# Why / When I should use the Backbone-relational framework

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-relational, backbone-model

I got a confusion sate now, any one clear my doubt and give more details about http://backbonerelational.org/ please?

basically,

1. Why we use the relational
2. When we need to take a decision to use that
3. Can't we achieve the same with Backone.js itself..?

i have this scenario, i have the sample json like this:

```
var navi = {
    "mainLinkLabel": "Home",
    "mainLinkHref": "/home.html",
    "sublinks": [
        {
            "sublinkLabel": "subHome1",
            "sublinkHref": "/home/home1.html"
        },
        {
            "sublinkLabel": "subHome2",
            "sublinkHref": "/home/home2.html"
        },
        {
            "sublinkLabel": "subHome3",
            "sublinkHref": "/home/home3.html"
        }
    ]
}
```

it has the mainlink and sublinks:

for this I should make the model as like to cover the both info:

```
var bothModels =  Backbone.Model.extend({

    defautls:{

        "mainLinkLable" : "default Lable",
        "mainLinkHref"  : "#",
        "sublinks"      : [
            "sublinkLabel" : "default sublink",
            "sublinkHref"  : "#"
        ]

    }

})
```

or i need to make separate models for each and connect with Backbone-relational.. like this?

```
var mainModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defautls:{

        "mainLinkLable" : "default Lable",
        "mainLinkHref"  : "#"

    }
})

var subModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults:{
             "sublinkLabel" : "default sublink",
             "sublinkHref"  : "#"
    }
})
```

if so, how can i connect these both models.. and what would be the benefit will i get. I search across the internet to find some simple tutorial to understand this.. But i couldn't come with some..

any one clarify me this scenario please..?

[Here is the fiddle to play](http://jsfiddle.net/ySKQW/)

Comment: You are taking the right approach. Create 2 separate models. And the first Model would have a attribute that would again be a collection sub models. By doing this you would have sublinks as a Nested collection inside the model. This will allow all the dependent data to be on a single model instead of a separate collection outside the model

Comment: sounds good. can you show me or update fiddle for a live demo.. and there is no work for backbone-relational here..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i have not worked with Backbone relational before. But I would construct the structure, using 2 models and having a `parse` method on the model and passing the main collection.

```
var navi = {
    "mainLinkLabel": "Home",
    "mainLinkHref": "/home.html",
    "sublinks": [{
        "sublinkLabel": "subHome1",
        "sublinkHref": "/home/home1.html"
    }, {
        "sublinkLabel": "subHome2",
        "sublinkHref": "/home/home2.html"
    }, {
        "sublinkLabel": "subHome3",
        "sublinkHref": "/home/home3.html"
    }]
};


var MainModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defauts: {
        "mainLinkLable": "default Lable",
        "mainLinkHref": "#"
    },
    parse: function(response) {
        if(response.sublinks) {
             this.subCollection = new SubCollection(response.sublinks || null, { parse: true });
        }
        delete response.sublinks;
        
        return response;
    }
})

var SubModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        "sublinkLabel": "default sublink",
        "sublinkHref": "#"
    }
});

var MainCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: MainModel
});

var SubCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: SubModel 
});

var mainCollection = new MainCollection(navi, {parse : true});

console.log(mainCollection);
```

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/ySKQW/1/)**

So if you want access the sublinks collection inside each model . You would just use

`this.subCollection` which would give you the collection in question.

Comment: Shushath, thanks for your initiative, still can you look in to alexanderb's answer please..?

Answer (score 1):

Backbone.js does not support nested models from the box. In reality, you deal with nested models much: invoices contains lines, departements contains employees etc.

You should look into you bussine model, if you have nested models as above, `Backbone.Relational` will help you.

You basically can't archive that with `Backbone.js` itself, expect of writing own custom code, to overload `parse` method of models. We did it on one of the project I work, but main lesson learnt - use time-prooven plugin instead of own wheel reinvention. And `Backbone.Relational` seems to be a good choice.

Comment: ok, but in my case how to i use the Backbone.relational.. can you give a clue.. please

Comment: checking out the examples is good to start: http://backbonerelational.org/#examples